Join Sum on another Query
I have two tables: RegisteredUsers and Soldtickets (this is an import from Stripe). I want to use a sum of all the sold tickets by PlayerID from Soldtickets in a query that selects all the data (select *) from RegisteredUsers. The PlayerID and Identifier from RegisteredUsers should be the same, and if there is no sum I would like to show a 0.
Any help is appreciated.
First Image is RegisteredUsers Table and Second is StripeImport



We don't post images of sample data or results here.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

And you say you've been having a go, so show us where you got to.

SELECT ru.*, coalesce(st.tickets, 0) As Tickets
FROM RegisteredUsers ru
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT PlayerID, SUM(Qty) As Tickets
   FROM SoldTickets
   GROUP BY PlayerID
) st ON st.PlayerID = ru.Identifier


So I got that working and I trying to put in a Where statement to only select the top 50 PKs so I can do email batches but the where statement doesnt work.

SELECT ru.*, coalesce(st.tickets, 0) As Tickets
FROM RegisteredUser ru
Where PK between '1' and '50'
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT PlayerID, SUM(Qty) As Tickets
FROM StripeImport
GROUP BY PlayerID
) st ON st.PlayerID = ru.Identifier
Order by Tickets desc

Ask a new question then... because this answers what you asked.

SELECT ru.*, coalesce(st.tickets, 0) As Tickets
FROM RegisteredUser ru
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT PlayerID, SUM(Qty) As Tickets
   FROM StripeImport
   GROUP BY PlayerID
) st ON st.PlayerID = ru.Identifier
Where PK between '1' and '50'
Order by Tickets desc


You've already accepted an answer? Why have you added another? And please make use of the code formatting option in the editor.

please make clear/edit your answer explaining why it is another useful answer, since one answer was already accepted
